# iOS/macOS audio player with millisecond-level delay control?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, audio, software-recommendation

I'm trying to perform an amateur experiment related with sound waves. Let's say I have a file on my iCloud Drive, let's call it `wave1.wav`. I want to play it on my Mac/iPhone, but with a slider or another way of controlling the playback *delay* at the level of single milliseconds.

Does such app exist? It can be a feature of some commercial music mixing software, as long as it's cheap  (< 20 USD) or has a free trial.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you could use [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) (free software).

It has keyboard shortcuts ('j' and 'k') for decreasing/increasing audio delay in steps of 50 ms. In the Advanced Settings, you can set it as a numeric value giving you more precision over the actual delay.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about the 50ms option, but I had no idea it’s configurable. I’ll check it out.